# Why is test() returning True when it should fail?

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex

I have this code and I am wondering why it logs *true*:

```
console.log(/[A-Za-z0-9-_:]/.test('zoom^Bar'));
```

I would assume the caret character would make the regex fail, why is it passing?

Just want to say this question is straightforward but might help others and the "duplicate" question doesn't really like a simple dupe to me.

Comment: It doesn't check for whole string. It checks whether a character from character set matches in input string.

Comment: I tried with the /g flag and still same thing

Comment: how do I make it test the whole string?

Comment: You are looking for `console.log(/^[A-Za-z0-9-_:]+$/.test('zoom^Bar'));`

Comment: @revo Or just `console.log(/^[\w-:]+$/.test('zoom^Bar'));`

Comment: @revo thanks that seems to work, can you explain why in an answer?

Comment: The function `test` returns true because it finds a match. You need anchors to ensure that no other characters are present throughout the string. This question is a very likely to be a duplicate.

Comment: perhaps there is a better method than `RegExp.prototype.test` to use then?

Comment: You don't need another function, just use the correct regex. @revo's pattern can be simplified to `^[\w-:]+$`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness move that hyphen to the start or end of the character class, otherwise you're matching a range between `\w` and `:`, ie `^[\w:-]+$`

Comment: I don't think that's necessary here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
console.log(/^[A-Za-z0-9-_:]+$/.test('zoom^Bar'))
```

Comment: @MrCholo Your original regex matches a single character, while this one matches one or more characters (see the + before the end). Also, this matches the entire string, ^ denotes start, $ denotes end. Hence, it return false.

Comment: Of course. In the regex you have used, it looks for one of the letters from A-Z or 0-9 or etc... even if the word would be `a^{}÷π` it would pass because it found 'a' occurance. So you just needed to add the start sign `^` Then the letters you want to appear in the word, and then `+` sign which says that those letters have to appear one or more times, and then the finish sign `$`

Comment: The hyphen is in the wrong place in your character class. To include a literal hyphen, put it first or last in the set (or escape it). See https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html

Comment: It doesnt matter, as long as the `-` isnt between two chars its definitily fine to use it this way